# How to resolve database mirroring error 1418?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have been trying to perform database mirroring between two different servers on the same network. However, I have been constantly getting error code 1418.

I have ensured

1. that both of the ports on the two servers are listening and endpoints are sucessfully established
2. the firewall is not blocking anything
3. I can ping the other server on either machine, but the error still appears.

I was wondering if the problem could be the two servers not being in the same domain (it's only in the same network I'm not entirely sure if that's the same thing).
I was also wondering how should I proceed to turn the current account into a domain account if that is the issue.

Comment: Does this help at all? https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/blob/live/docs/database-engine/database-mirroring/setting-up-database-mirroring-sql-server.md